# How to enable Info Windows Open on Default With CI google map library

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

I am using **[biostall's codeigniter google map library](http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library)** for my google map display. I followed the instruction to display info windows and had the map displayed properly on the page. And currently the info window only opens when clicked on the pointer. Progress so far is like the purple icon displayed in demo.  Click for **[Quick demo](http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/multiplemarkers)**.

I wasn't able to make the info window open on default. Please advise.

Configuration code as per below:

```
// map
$this->load->library('googlemaps');
// Initialize our map. Here you can also pass in additional parameters for customising the map (see below) 
$config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
$config['zoom'] = '14';
$config['map_width'] = '500px';
$this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

// set markers
$marker = array();
$marker['position'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
$marker['infowindow_content'] = '<b>We are here!!</b>;
$marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
$this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

// Create the map. This will return the Javascript to be included in our pages <head></head> section and the HTML code to be placed where we want the map to appear. 
$data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and your solution with the simulated clicked worked fine.
But I my info window was too big / my zoom too high / my map-div too small, so the map-div clipped the info window.
So I modified your codeline a little bit, and this problem was also solved.

```
$config["onload"] = 'window.setTimeout("google.maps.event.trigger(marker_0, \'click\');",300);';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using my library. Try adding this to the list of $config parameters:

```
$config['onload'] = "google.maps.event.trigger(marker_0, 'click');";
```

This will essentially mimic a click on the first marker when the page loads.

I haven't tested this but it should work. If it doesn't let me know and I'll take a closer look.

Good luck!